# App takes too long to update UIView

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, asynchronous

In short, I have an app that is meant to display a bunch of data that is stored locally in the phone, in CoreData.

I pull the data from CoreData and then I add about 70 subviews to the main UIView. This causes the app to freeze(not respond) until it has added all the subviews to the main view.

I would like to find a way to add asyncronously all subviews so that the app doesnt freeze.

I tried to use `performSelectorOnMainThread` but it takes the same amount of time.

What can I do?

thanks.

[EDIT]
The view has to update itself everytime a button is pressed, so each time the button is pressed it searchs in the DB and updates the view, which means deleting all the subviews previously added and adds roughly 70 subviews to the main view.

This is a bit how the code looks:

```
currentEventsArray = I GET THE EVENTS FROM COREDATA
for(int i = 0; i < [currentEventsArray count]; i++){
    //I DO SEVERAL OPERATIONS WITH THE DATA AND THEN FINALLY...
    [self.view addsubview:aEventView];
 }
```

The currentEventsArray can have from 50 to 80 events
Instead of waiting till it has gone through all the events, could I add the subview independently and not to be added all the same time?

Comment: I think you have to add all subview on viewWillApear, and after that only set values.

Comment: not really, because the view has to be updated on user demand

Comment: Have you looked at building the list of subviews in your background thread and then just using the main thread call to add/change the subviews in your main view?

Comment: @gaige Could you point me some references so I can take a look?

Comment: Also see I edited the question, so it's clearer

Comment: Do you always replace the views with every refresh or do you only replace views where the data has changed?

Comment: always because everytime the view has to be refreshed it has different data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using a background thread to read the data and create the views and then add the views to the main view on your main thread.   Something like this:

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),  ^{
    currentEventsArray = /*I GET THE EVENTS FROM COREDATA*/;
    NSMutableArray *newViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0; i < [currentEventsArray count]; i++){
        //I DO SEVERAL OPERATIONS WITH THE DATA AND THEN FINALLY...
        [newViews addObject: aEventView];
    }
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // add or replace your subviews to the main view.
    }
});
```

And do that when you need to refresh the data.    Keep in mind that you probably don't want this happening more than one at a time.  You can do this by putting a flag in your Controller to make sure you don't do the initial dispatch_async if one is already running, or you can queue another attempt by using a private dispatch queue instead  of the global background queue.

If you choose to use your own background queue, then you will want to create an instance variable in your calling class (controller) and when you load it you'll want to create a new queue:

```
_updateQueue = dispatch_queue_create( "UpdateQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

and use that in place of the:

```
dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)
```

above.